# Display Total Number of Social Shares

Tags: functions

I have to display the total number of social shares, like mashable does in it´s website.

[image]

It´s not a problem, I found a php code that does the job.

```
function getTotalShares($atts) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'cache' => '3600',
    'url' => 0,
    'f' => 0,
    'bgcolor' => '#ffffff',
    'bordercolor' => '#ffffff',
    'borderwidth' => '0',
    'bordertype' => 'solid',
    'fontcolor' => '#7fc04c',
    'fontsize' => '55',
    'fontweight' => 'normal',
    'padding' => '1'
  ), $atts));

 $shareHash = "$cache.$url.$f.$bgcolor.$bordercolor.$borderwidth.$bordertype.$fontcolor.$fontsize.$fontweight.$padding";
 $totalShareRecord = 'totalshares_' . $shareHash;
 $cachedposts = get_transient($totalShareRecord);
 if ($cachedposts !== false) {
 return $cachedposts;

 } else {

   if (!$url) $url = get_permalink($post->ID);

   $json = file_get_contents("http://api.sharedcount.com/?url=" . rawurlencode($url));
    $counts = json_decode($json, true);
    $return = $counts['Twitter'] + $counts['Facebook']['total_count'] + $counts['GooglePlusOne'];
    if ($f) $return = '' . $return . '';
    set_transient($totalShareRecord, $return, $cache);
    return $return;
 }
}
add_shortcode('totalshares','getTotalShares');
```

Now the problematic!

The code above get the numbers of shares based on the permalink, which is pulled by `get_permalink($post->ID);`. My website works as a content aggregator, so I want to pull the number of shares of the original post url, which in my website is filled in the post meta `links_link_custom`. My question is: Is this possible?

I hope this text is not confusing, please comment if more information is needed.

Comment: Well, it **is** (a bit) confusing. Wouldn't you just have to replace `if (!$url) $url = get_permalink($post->ID);` with `if (!$url) $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'links_link_custom', true);` and that's it?

Comment: Where did you get the PHP code from and do you have an example of the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

Replace
`if (!$url) $url = get_permalink($post->ID);`

with

`$post_id = get_the_ID();
$url = get_post_meta("$post_id", 'links_link_custom', true);`